# How does Postman to generate this cookie?

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, oauth, postman

```
import requests

url = "https://apiexample.com/load/v1/action/aaaaaaaaaaaaa"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="aaaaaa",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1664837015",oauth_nonce="mKyTFn7OtsV",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="aaaaaaaaaaaa"',
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=M7n-S-aGe8asRnTjNOUGowak5i5avsRBx6A4H8au.madsedepre'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I am trying to retrieve information from an api, and I am using postman...

How can I know what postman is doing to generate that cookie??
and how can I generate it using python requests?

Comment: Hey, where did you get the headers for the request from? Did you copy these from your browser? Or did a request you made in postman return them? Or something else?

Comment: @MattieTK I copied the headers from Postman, seems like it detects how to generate the cookie and how to generate the signature